# Match special characters at the end of string with Regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to match special characters appearing at the end of a string or word. Special characters are `\.,;:-_`.

What regex pattern can be used for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the regex `\w+[\\.:;_,-]+(?= |$)`

Use something like this , in your java code:

```
    String val="dev\\ devendra. devendra, dev dev, dev; devendra: wan.gikar devendra: windchill- windchill- serviceCenter_ sC_Windchill";
    String REGEX="\\w+[\\\\.:;_,-]+(?= |$)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(val);
    while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

**Output**

```
dev\
devendra.
devendra,
dev,
dev;
devendra:
devendra:
windchill-
windchill-
serviceCenter_
```

Refer **[this](http://regex101.com/r/yA6vF5)** , for more details .

**Explanation :**

[image]

Comment: How can i remove only the special characters for such kinds of words which ends in special characters?

Answer (score 5):

`$` matches end of string so try:

```
[\\.,;:\-_]+$
```

Since `\` is special regular expression characters you should escape it with `\` so it becomes `\\` in regular expression. Also `-` in [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) has special meaning because it is used to create range of characters like `a-z` so you will need to escape it.

Also since you are asking about Java you need to know that `\` need to be written as `"\\"` because it is also special character in String literal, so String with regex will look like

```
"[\\\\.,;:\\-_]+$"
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `.` in `[...]` but it would be nice to escape `-` since it is used to create range of characters inside character class like `[a-z]`.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that since . is a regex char it should be also escaped.

Comment: Normally it would, but `[]` is also nice mechanism to escape some special characters, for example you can escape this way `[*]` `[$]` and many others regex metacharacters.

Comment: Also, since Devendra is asking about special character*s*, you should probably use a `+` to match one or more of these.

Comment: [\\\\.,;:\\-_]$ didn't work.  when I removed $ from it, all special characters are matched but not only those who are at end of string/word. pls suggest working expression.

Comment: @DevendraW It works for me. You need to say something more about how you are using this regex and what do you mean by "end of string/word". Edit your question and include input and expected result.

Comment: My input is 

dev\
devendra.
devendra, dev
dev,
dev;
devendra: wangikar
devendra:
windchill- 
windchill-
serviceCenter_
sC_Windchill

and output should be 

only follwing string should be matched


dev\
devendra.
dev,
dev;
devendra:
windchill- 
windchill-
serviceCenter_

Comment: @DevendraW It seems you are confusing String with word. String may contain only one word like `"word"` but words can be part of larger String like `"word1 word2 word3"`. In this case end of String would be after `word3`. There is no end of String after `word1` or `word2` (String doesn't end here because there are other characters after these words). That is why I asked you to edit your question and post code you are using with example input. So once again [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21226850/edit) your question and post code that will let us reproduce problem with regex.